# getting the response body of HttpResponse

Tags: android, http, entity

I have done this:

```
response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httppost); 
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
                        {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Entity:"+entity);
  if (entity != null) 
                            {
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println("finalResult"+responseBody.toString());
                            }
```

The thing about it is that the first `println()` displays this: `org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@481e8150` which is good.

But the second `System.out.println("finalResult"+responseBody.toString());` displays only this `finalResult`. So what is wrong with this:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println("finalResult"+responseBody.toString());
```

???

**IMPORTANT** This `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();` is equal to `org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@481e8150`. SO the problem must be here:

String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, see if your server is not returning blank response:

```
response.getEntity().getContentLength();  //it should not be 0
```

Second, try the following to convert response into string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()), 65728);
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }


System.out.println("finalResult " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: then it means there's no data returned from your webservice

Comment: but when I display HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();      System.out.println("finalResult " + entity); it shows org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@48246b10. This means the response from webservice is not null, right?

Comment: try logging `response.getEntity().getContentLength();` and see if the content length is more than **0** otherwise you are getting nothing from server

Comment: It means your object is not null which is good, but then it doesn't mean that your object does contain data inside.

Comment: yes, its 0, so it means your server is returning blank response :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11583/discussion-between-adrian-and-waqas)

Comment: Hey, I am using the same code but getting Exception"attempted read from closed stream android". Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: @SalmanKhan make sure you are not reading/using the stream once it is consumed and/or closed.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this one:

```
String s = EntityUtils.toString(httpRes.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@f8a5dec
```

response come when we directly print HttpEntity object. eg:

```
 HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Now for getting the actual Response from the server we need to do following steps:

```
 public String convertStreamtoString(InputStream is){

    String line="";
    String data="";
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

            data+=line;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return  data;
}
```

just call above method and pass httpEntity as an argument. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String body = "";
while ((body = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{
    Log.e("HttpResponse", body);
}
```

Comment: rd is java.io.BufferedReader@48073398. but body = rd.readLine(); is null!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
final String content;
    try
    {
        content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                webView.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent()));

                //SB to make a string out of the inputstream
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();

                //the json string is stored here
            String  result = sb.toString();
```