# Receiving empty JSON array from GET request

Tags: java, android, json, object

I am running an `asyncTask` to retrieve a JSON array of objects from a `HttpPost`.

The output from the webservice is:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "What town were you born in?"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "What is your mothers maiden name?"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Who was your childhood hero?"
    }
]
```

But get the `JSONException`:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Which refers to `JArray` in the following code:

```
JSONArray JArray;

Context ra;

public SecurityQuestionsTask(Context _registerActivity) {
    ra = _registerActivity;
    JArray = new JSONArray();
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String... langs) {

    Long result = 0L;

    String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

    String[] langArray = {"en", "de", "fr"};

    if (!Arrays.asList(langArray).contains(lang)) {
        lang = "en";
    }

    try {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://webservice.com/api/v1/securityquestions?lang=" + lang);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            JSONString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            JArray = new JSONArray(JSONString);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    publishProgress("Retrieving security questions...");

    return result;
}
```

Am I parsing the `response` to a `JSONArray` correctly?

edit:

This is how the webservice responds:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(json.toString()).build();
```

Comment: Is EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"); returning the expected JSON string? And is it assigned to a variable that is passed to JSONArray constructor?

Comment: Share same response which getting in `JSONString` because exception saying trying to convert invalid string to JSONArray or JSONObject

Comment: Did you try to input your expected data to `JSONString` variable like  `JSONString = "[{\"id\": 1,\"question\": \"What town were you born in?\"}]"`? It is required to diagnose whether your error is from http communication or content parsing.

Comment: @Youngjae I just did this and it is not building the `JSONString` from response.

Comment: The webserver converts a `JSONArray` to a `String` before sending it as a `Response` entity. Is this correct?

Comment: @crm // webserver can convert data to Json string before making a Response entity or can _serialize_ at the end of http output. It depends on the server application design, configuration, or response handling so it cannot say correct or not.

Comment: @crm // would you please check this link?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10684086/361100  seems duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

The clue was in the question title it seems!

I had to use `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost` with the way I have my web service setup.

so this line:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://webservice.com/api/v1/securityquestions?lang=" + lang);
```

had to change to this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://webservice.com/api/v1/securityquestions?lang=" + lang);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `String` response is like the one you posted, try

```
     // Execute HTTP Post Request
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
     JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(resp);
```

Comment: I need the JSONArray to be a class object so I can use it to populate a list in the `onPostExecute` method of an `AsycTask`.

Comment: `jsonArray` can be a object member, no problem, just remove the declaration `JSONArray` in front and declare `jsonArr` in the class like you actually do.